# Javascript problem using Three.js texture function

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I am trying to build a snakes and ladders game in javascript in which I have a 100x100 grid. I want each of the the tiles to be different. In my arr[], I have each of the 100 different photos from 1-100. I want to make loader1.load, loader2.load.. into a loop where i load each of these and put them into an array called wall_texture.

Then I want to go into my initScene() method and make my thecube.material, and try and make these textures one by one.

I am having problems when I try do this, I am not sure if it is do with trying to call a function within a loop or maybe something to do with Three.js but any help would be appreciated.

```
    loader1.load ( arr[1], function ( thetexture )       
    {
        thetexture.minFilter  = THREE.LinearFilter;
        wall_texture = thetexture;
        if ( asynchFinished() ) initScene();         
    });


    loader2.load ( arr[2], function ( thetexture )       
    {
        thetexture.minFilter  = THREE.LinearFilter;
        wall_texture2 = thetexture;
        if ( asynchFinished() ) initScene();         
    });

initScene()
{
    // set up board
     
     for ( i = 0; i < gridsize ; i++ ) 
      for ( j = 0; j < gridsize ; j++ ) 
        {
            GRID[i][j] = true;       
            shape    = new THREE.BoxGeometry ( squaresize, squaresize, squaresize );             
            thecube  = new THREE.Mesh( shape );

            **thecube.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: wall_texture[i] } );**

            
            
            thecube.position.copy ( translate(i,j) );// translate my (i,j) grid coordinates to three.js (x,y,z) coordinates
            ABWorld.scene.add(thecube);
        }
}
```

I have tried the above.

Comment: "I am having problems when I try do this", .... can you elaborate, or provide some errors you're receiving?

Comment: None of the textures show up when i load my game is the problem. I do not get any errors in the code compiler.

Comment: There are too many errors here to list them all. Just to get started, `new THREE.Mesh()` needs a geometry and a material, you're only passing `shape`, so who knows how it'll behave. Then you're using [exponent symbols `**`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation) for no reason. Finally you can't access `wall_texture2` by invoking `wall_texture[i]`, since the latter is an array.